# Prohibited attributes in a Typescript Interface

Tags: interface, typescript, typescript1.4

I was to create a TypeScript interface that not only requires that particular attributes are present, but also prohibits attributes that are not part of the definition.  Here is an example:

```
  export interface IComponentDirective {
    scope : any;
    templateUrl : string;
  };

  var ddo : IComponentDirective = {
    scope: {
      dt: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'directives.datepicker',
    controller: function() {
      console.log('hello world');
    }
  };
```

Even though `controller` is not defined in the interface, the `ddo` assignment doesn't throw an error.   Doing some research, this looks like it might be as designed:

> Notice that our object actually has more properties than this, but the
>   compiler only checks to that at least the ones required are present
>   and match the types required.
>
> http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces

Notice, however, that after I declare `ddo` as a `IComponentDirective`, if I try something like:

```
ddo.transclude = false;
```

The transpiler will complain with:

> 2339 Property 'transclude' does not exist on type
>   'IComponentDirective'.

Is there any way to enforce a tighter contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short (but depending on your definition of "tighter") you can't restrict things beyond this.

The interface is a contract that says "if these members are not present, you aren't one of these". If your object happens to have additional members, that's fine; when you are using the interface, they are invisible to you.

For example (based on your code), when you type `ddo.` it will only suggest the members on the interface, because you have told the compiler to use the interface type.

You can't use an interface to *prevent* a member being defined. I can't think of any language that does this off the top of my head. For example, in C# you can implement more than the interface requires you to implement, but when you are using the interface type, those other members are not available.

## Adding Properties Dynamically

The question as to why `ddo.tranclude = false;` generates a warning is a bit different. This isn't related to interfaces - it will do it when there is no interface:

```
  var ddo = {
    scope: {
      dt: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'directives.datepicker',
    controller: function() {
      console.log('hello world');
    }
  };

  ddo.transclude = false; // Nope
```

The reason for this is... this is the point of TypeScript! It is warning you that you might have typed `transclude` incorrectly. Perhaps you meant `templateUrl`, which *does* exist. If TypeScript didn't warn you about this kind of problem, it would allow you to introduce typographical bugs into your code.

So TypeScript will generate a type for any object you create and then enforce that structure, unless you tell it otherwise.

If you wanted there to "sometimes be a `transclude` member" you can make that possible:

```
interface SometimesTransclude {
    scope: { dt: string};
    templateUrl: string;
    controller: () => void;
    transclude?: boolean;
}

  var ddo: SometimesTransclude = {
    scope: {
      dt: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'directives.datepicker',
    controller: function() {
      console.log('hello world');
    }
  };

  ddo.transclude = false;
```

Or you can dance straight past the compiler (at your own risk) using:

```
ddo['transclude'] = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply!  This makes sense in the classical sense of an Interface, but why then would it throw when you do `ddo.transclude = false;`?

Comment: I have added a section on this - as it isn't really to do with interfaces specifically.

Comment: Hmmm, I understand the option param, but if it's going to warn me about `transclude`, shouldn't it have warned me about controller?  I feel like either it should act like a classical interface or it should warn about unknown attributes, but it seems like it's being inconsistent.  Also, I didn't know about the `dancing past the compiler` - this is a little scary.

Comment: Here is the interesting distinction. TypeScript is structurally typed and will generate a type for you when you create a variable - and enforce that generated type. That means you can put anything you like on `ddo` when you first create it - but after that, the type is checked. (I go into a lot of detail about this in my book... hint hint ;) )

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I'm not a huge fan of how this works, but I think your description deserves the check mark. :)