# React, TypeScript conditional props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a React component with conditional props using a piped type between two interfaces. I have it set up like this:

```js
interface BaseProps {
  "aria-label"?: string;
  className?: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
}

interface IconProps extends BaseProps {
  "aria-label": string;
  children: never;
  icon: React.ReactElement;
}

interface ButtonProps extends BaseProps {
  children: React.ReactElement;
}

type Props = ButtonProps | IconProps;

class Button extends React.Component<Props> {
  render(): React.ReactElement {
    const { children, icon, ...rest } = this.props;
    // ERROR: "Property 'icon' does not exist on type '(Readonly<ButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>) | (Readonly<IconProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>)'."
  }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the following:

1. When there is an "icon" prop, force "aria-label" and disallow children
2. When there is not an "icon" prop, force children and allow optional "aria-label"

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a union between the two variants:

```
interface VariantWithIconProps {
  icon: React.ReactElement,
  "aria-label": string;
}

interface VariantNoIconProps {
  "aria-label"?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode,
}

type Props = VariantWithIconProps | VariantNoIconProps;

const iconProps: VariantWithIconProps = {
  icon: <svg/>,
  "aria-label": "a",
};
const props1: Props = iconProps;
const props2: VariantNoIconProps = iconProps; // typescript error

const noIconProps1: VariantNoIconProps = {
  children: <div/>
};
const props3: Props = noIconProps1;
const props4: VariantWithIconProps = noIconProps1;  // typescript error

const noIconProps2: VariantNoIconProps = {
  children: <div/>,
  'aria-label': "a"
};
const props5: Props = noIconProps2;
const props6: VariantWithIconProps = noIconProps2;  // typescript error
```

Unfortunately it looks like prohibiting attributes in an interface isn't easily done without a workaround.

- [Is it possible to restrict typescript object to contain only properties defined by its class ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined)
- [Prohibited attributes in a Typescript Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926191/prohibited-attributes-in-a-typescript-interface)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this only works for pure TS, but not with React. I ended up having to use the `UnionKeys`, `StrictUnionHelper`, and `StrictUnion` types from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771362/typescript-react-union-type-for-props-does-not-display-error-when-providing-exc